# ping 8.8.8.8 connect: Network is unreachable?

Tags: networking, server, network-manager, dns, ethernet

When i `ping 8.8.8.8` it says: `connect: Network is unreachable`

```
$vi /etc/resolv/.conf

nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 192.168.0.5

$vi /etc/network/interfaces
# This file describes the network interfaces available on your system
# and how to activate them. For more information, see interfaces(5).

source /etc/network/interfaces.d/*

# The loopback network interface
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The primary network interface
allow-hotplug eth1
iface eth1 inet dhcp

auth eth1
iface eth1 inet static
address 192.168.56.101
netmask 255.255.255.o

$ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:ac:81:49 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:63:e1:93 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.56.101/24 brd 192.168.56.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe63:e193/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: You should tell us why you expect the network should be reachable... checked all connections, etc

Comment: How can eth1 be *both* static and dhcp???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems from your `192.168.56.*` address that you are running in a VirtualBox image, and that you are wondering why the image has no connectivity when presumably your host does.

You have probably set the first eth0 interface to "NAT" or "bridged", and attached it to your host's ethernet interface. If you are online via wifi but your bridge/NAT is configured to use the ethernet card, you won't have network connectivity; the reverse is also true.

Change the network interface of the VM to use the correct host interface.